# Adding onclick events with counter to a table td in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I am interested in adding a counter to a click event; after a number of attempted clicks, I would like to prevent them and restart over. I considered adding a `div` by nesting the table inside of it, and it did not work. What is the simplest way of doing this?

```js
var td = document.querySelectorAll("#td td");
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;
var loc = [rand + 3, rand + 1, rand + 2];
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
  td[loc[i]].onclick = function() {
    this.style.color = 'red';
    this.textContent = 'X';
  }
}
td.onclick = function() {
  counter += 1;
  if (counter == 10) {
    alert("Game Over");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <h1> Battleship</h1>
  <table id="td">
    <tr>
      <td id="A1">W</td>
      <td id="A2">W</td>
      <td id="A3">W</td>
      <td id="A4">W</td>
      <td id="A5">W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="B1">W</td>
      <td id="B2">W</td>
      <td id="B3">W</td>
      <td id="B4">W</td>
      <td id="B5">W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="C1">W</td>
      <td id="C2">W</td>
      <td id="C3">W</td>
      <td id="C4">W</td>
      <td id="C5">W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="D1">W</td>
      <td id="D2">W</td>
      <td id="D3">W</td>
      <td id="D4">W</td>
      <td id="D5">W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="E1">W</td>
      <td id="E2">W</td>
      <td id="E3">W</td>
      <td id="E4">W</td>
      <td id="E5">W</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please first fix your snippet so it is error free

Comment: add an counter. just use a global variable and increment it.

Comment: @mplungjan, the error is what I am trying to fix.

Comment: `var td` is an array, try adding an event listener to each item in the array

Comment: Your question is not mentioning any error. You have an error in the statement `td[loc[i]].onclick = function() {` since you only have 3 loc and not 25 - perhaps you mean `for (var i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do this - one last issue, your loc will sometimes have values larger than the grid. You need to decide how to tackle that.

Also you can have ONE onclick and check the cell's index against loc to see if you hit or not

```js
var td = document.querySelectorAll("#td td");
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;
var loc = [rand + 3, rand + 1, rand + 2];
console.log(rand,loc)
var counter = 0;


function checkCounter() {
  counter++;
  if (counter == 10) {
    alert("Game Over");
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
  if (loc.indexOf(i) !=-1) {
    td[i].onclick = function() {
      if (counter>= 10) return;
      this.style.color = 'red';
      this.textContent = 'X';
      checkCounter();
    }
  }
  else {
    td[i].onclick = function() {
      if (counter>= 10) return;      
      this.style.color = 'green';
      this.textContent = 'X';
      checkCounter();
    }
  }  
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <h1> Battleship</h1>
  <table id="td">
    <tr>
      <td id="A1">W</td>
      <td id="A2">W</td>
      <td id="A3">W</td>
      <td id="A4">W</td>
      <td id="A5">W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="B1">W</td>
      <td id="B2">W</td>
      <td id="B3">W</td>
      <td id="B4">W</td>
      <td id="B5">W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="C1">W</td>
      <td id="C2">W</td>
      <td id="C3">W</td>
      <td id="C4">W</td>
      <td id="C5">W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="D1">W</td>
      <td id="D2">W</td>
      <td id="D3">W</td>
      <td id="D4">W</td>
      <td id="D5">W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="E1">W</td>
      <td id="E2">W</td>
      <td id="E3">W</td>
      <td id="E4">W</td>
      <td id="E5">W</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong after the for loop declaration. Remove the loc[i] on your code and change it to i

```
var td = document.querySelectorAll("#td td");
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;
var loc = [rand + 3, rand + 1, rand + 2];
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    td[i].onclick = function() {
    this.style.color = 'red';
    this.textContent = 'X';
    counter += 1;
    if (counter == 10) {
       alert("Game Over");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `loc[i]` is required and I need to have it there. Thansk.

Comment: your loc[i] is using the variable from the for loop which is more than the length of the loc array. you must generate a random that will generate a number only from 0 - 2 since array starts from 0.